# How to add "Upgrades" entity to product-order database design?

Tags: database-design, e-commerce, data-modeling

I'm working on a database design for an e-commerce web application. For this question I am simplifying the design and only showing the parts that are relevant to my question.

My things of interest (entities) in this scenario are `Products`, `Upgrades`, and `Orders`.

The `Products` and `Orders` are related in a typical fashion for this type of database design, with an `OrderItems` table to create the many-to-many relationship:

```
Products
--------
ProductID (pk)
Name
Description
Price

Orders
------
OrderID (pk)
DateOrderPlaced

OrderItems
----------
OrderID (fk, cpk)
ProductID (fk, cpk)
Quantity
```

Now I'm wondering how to add `Upgrades` into the mix:

- an `Upgrade` can be valid for one or more `Products`
- an `OrderItem` can involve zero or more valid `Upgrades`

For instance, say I have these records in `OrderItems` making up Order #1:

```
OrderID    ProductID
-------    ---------
1          1
1          2
1          3
```

And I want to apply Upgrade #1 to Product #1 and #2...

I can imagine adding an `Upgrades` table and an `OrderItemUpgrades` table, which will allow me to apply any number of `Upgrades` to a given `OrderItem` (line in an `Order`).

```
Upgrades
--------
UpgradeID (pk)
Name
Description
Price

OrderItemUpgrades
-----------------
OrderID (fk, cpk)
ProductID (fk, cpk)
UpgradeID (fk, cpk)
```

I think of this as modeling the "application" of an `Upgrade` to a `Product` in an `Order`.

My question is, where do I model the "validity" of a given `Upgrade` for a given `Product`? Should I add a `ValidProductUpgrades` table that relates Upgrades and Products (or another database layer solution)? Or does that business logic belong at the application layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do exactly what you have shown in your final code block above. In this case it makes sense to add a separate table that will actually connect the upgrade to a specific order while keeping the product in mind.

Because upgrades can be valid for one OR more products, and with that in mind there could be more than one upgrade applied to a single product; it also makes sense to have the ValidProductUpgrades table, which could then be queried to make sure upgrades for a product are displayed only if they are able to be applied to said product.

I think your assumption above is complete, and is probably the best way to handle this!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Wade, this is helpful as third-party confirmation that I'm going about this the right way!